# Difference between portable class library and shared class library in Xamarin cross platform

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can any one explain the difference between portable class library and shared class library in Xamarin cross platform

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/

Answer (score 6):

Just my understanding about them.

shared class library works as static library (shared source code) and portable library likes a dynamic library.

[image: Shared]
[image: Portable]

Comment: Coming from a C++ app building background, this clears things up for me.

Answer (score 4):

A portable library is a compiled piece of code that is referenced by other projects; the result of compilation is an assembly that is loaded by the referencing app at runtime. A shared project is not compiled into a stand-alone assembly; instead, all of the code in the project is included in the compilation of the referencing project as if you had added the files that are in the shared project directly to the referencing project. There are pros and cons to both approaches, but it seems that the community is gravitating towards PCLs. There are cases where the use of Shared Projects is still necessary, though (OpenTK being one such example).

Comment: "but it seems that the community is gravitating towards PCLs". This is very important. When I wanted to try out Xamarin.Forms I thought that shared projects are what I want. The problem is that really most samples and examples are PCL, making it a lot harder to jump in for not-so seasoned developers (like me). Thats why I switched to PCL and would now recommend the same for other people like me.